# Display two column values as two row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, unpivot

I am using SQL Server 2012 for my database. Now, I have one table with following details.

```
ID                COLUMN1              COLUMN2
1                    A                    B
```

Now i want result like this.

```
ID                   Values
1                       A   
1                       B
```

Can any one suggest me how to do? 
I know i can do using pivot or unpivot. but i dont know how to do? and is there other way to do this?

Please help me out to write query for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use UNPIVOT to get the final result:

```
select id, value
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (COLUMN1, COLUMN2)
) u;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f2a76/1)

Or you can use CROSS APPLY to get it:

```
select id, value
from yourtable
cross apply
(
  values ('COLUMN1', COLUMN1), ('COLUMN2', COLUMN2)
) c (col, value)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f2a76/2)

Answer (score 3):

```
select id, col1 as value
from your_table
union all
select id, col2 as value
from your_table
```